# The opposite of bardcore

Tags: single-word-requests

Bardcore are modern songs rewritten to sound medieval. Is there any word for the opposite, when old songs are rewritten to sound more modern?

Comment: *update* or *modernization* would be general terms. There are probably more specific terms in specific genres.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of two words:

***Remake*** ([Idoceonline](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/remake))

`a record or film that has the same music or story as one that was made before`

***cover*** or *cover version* ([Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cover+(music)))

`A recording or performance of a song that was previously recorded or made popular by another`

I would add the interesting, but a little bit general ***reinterpretation*** about which I found a sentence that reminded me of your request, although it does not perfectly correspond to it ([Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reinterpretation)):

`If you see a rap version of Shakespeare's "Romeo and Juliet," that is a reinterpretation.`

**Edit**: These words are not antonyms of "bardcore", since they refer to remaking any previous song, be it modern or old.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_version#:%7E:text=In%20popular%20music%2C%20a%20cover,or%20composer%20of%20a%20song.) you will find this sentence

> In popular music, a ***cover version***, ***remake***, ***cover song***, ***revival***, or simply ***cover***, is a new performance or recording by someone other than the original artist or composer of a song.

The word that caught my eye was ***revival***. [MWebster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revival) defines it as

`a new presentation or publication of something old`

However, it seems to be used more for whole trends of music, not for one particular song. So there are expressions like ***folk revival***, ***blues revival***, ***rock revival*** or even ***revival(ist) band***.

So, I am afraid that if you want to be precise, one single word will not do. You would need to say a ***rock revival song*** or ***blues revival song***, etc. - adding the name of the particular music trend and the word ***song*** (so as to differentiate it from the revival of a whole trend revival).

For more information you can check this similar question on the SE [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/33/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cover-and-a-remake-of-a-songhttps://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/33/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cover-and-a-remake-of-a-song) site, it might help you to pin down your term.

Comment: Can't one make a bardcore cover?

Comment: more than answer this is intended to be an investigation to help the OP understand the difficulty of finding the term he is looking for. One can do the cover of anything previous to it, yes.